# ggsci colour not mapping

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors

Having issues mapping the colour palettes to my graph.

Have tried method on ggsci site, below, and a method found in this forum, below that. Neither mapping. Any help appreciated.

Method 1: Fill black, add theme_bw(), then append the colour palette.
Have tried swapping out fill for colour etc.

```
p1 <- TidySymptoms %>% 
      count(word, sort = TRUE) %>% 
      filter(n > 150) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(n, word), fill = n)+
      geom_col(fill = "black") + 
      labs(x = "Count", y = NULL) + 
      theme_bw()

p2 <- p1 + scale_fill_jama()
p2
```

Method 2: using scale_color_manual

```
p1 <- TidySymptoms %>% 
      count(word, sort = TRUE) %>% 
      filter(n > 150) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(n, word), colour = word)+
      geom_col() + 
      scale_color_manual(values = pal_jama("default")(5))+
      labs(x = "Count", y = NULL)
```

Comment: Why are you doing `fill = n` *and* `fill = "black"` in the first code? In the second one, you should put `colour = word`  inside `aes()`.

Comment: OP, when you set `fill="black"` it will override that aesthetic if it is mapped within `aes()` - such as in `fill=n` earlier.   If you try to recolor by adding `scale_fill_jama()`, it's not going to do anything.  If you remove `fill="black"`, you should get the column color mapped to the column called `n` and then adding in `scale_fill_jama()` should change teh palette for you.  The same applies for `color=`.

Comment: In the second one, if I put colour = word INSIDE aes(), I get following error

Comment: @chemdork123 I've tried that and no luck. I figured that fill = "black" would override but was following example at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggsci/vignettes/ggsci.html.

Comment: @Stephane Laurent I've tried putting colour = word INSIDE aes() and get following error
<geom_col requires the following missing aesthetics: y> 
At a loss

Comment: @Magnetar Try to name the variables: `aes(x = n, y = word, color = word)`.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent This has worked, just had to change color to fill as was only adding colour to outline. Thank you!